# How to fix the compiler error CS0009 - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format?

Tags: c#, batch-file, dll, adodb, csc

I'm trying to [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option) the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library (ADODB) using the [csc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) C# compiler but I'm getting the error:

> fatal [error CS0009](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0009): Metadata file 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado\msado15.dll' could not be opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '

I have simplified the files to try tracking the problem.

Batch file `Compile.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -nologo -r:"C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado\msado15.dll" Code.cs
PAUSE >NUL
```

C# file `Code.cs`:

```
class Program {
  static void Main() {
    ADODB.Connection ADODBConnection = new ADODB.Connection();
    System.Console.WriteLine((ADODBConnection == null).ToString());
  }
}
```

I have tried [copying the dll to the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423938) and referencing it but got the same error.

I also have the compilers versions `...\v2.0.50727\csc.exe` and `...\v3.5\csc.exe` and the libraries versions `msado20.tlb`, `msado21.tlb`, `msado25.tlb`, `msado26.tlb`, `msado27.tlb`, `msado28.tlb` and `msado60.tlb`.

When I try the same on Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Framework 4 Console Application) it works. It creates `ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\obj\Debug\Interop.ADODB.dll` and references that instead but I don't know where it gets it from. I have tried searching for it in different folders.

Comment: Why oh why are you using ADODB with c# rather than ADO.Net?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Because I don't know any better. I will try to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the file that Visual Studio uses from [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?607037-RESOLVED-Why-is-it-so-hard-to-find-the-ADODB-assembly) (by searching online for `Interop.ADODB.dll file location`) and later [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/78976fa5-c1b9-428a-a228-ff03305d6392/adodbdll-not-loaded):

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\adodb.dll

Working `Compile.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -nologo -r:"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\adodb.dll" Code.cs
PAUSE >NUL
```